# Listbox options (similar to dropdown) overlapping

Tags: next.js, headless-ui

I am trying to develop a webpage by React.js, Next.js, TailwindCSS, and HeadlessUI. It accepts a couple of inputs (I used Listbox of HeadlessUI for this purpose), and they must be placed consecutively to let users specify the required information for the platform.

After testing the developed user interface, I witnessed an overlapping in Listbox options. As shown in the screenshot below, they need to be rendered properly, showing up on each other, which is not intended. I need to resolve this issue

[image]

In TailwindCSS's documentation, there should be a specific solution to this error within their defined **classNames**, but I have not found it yet. The solution can be relevant to bringing an object to the front

There are two probable destinations where I need to make a modification

1. ClassName of the ListboxOption ( mother component ):

```
className="absolute mt-1 max-h-60 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
```

2. ClassName of Listbox Options ( Child component ):

```
className = {
  ({
    active
  }) =>
  `relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-10 pr-4 ${active ? 'bg-amber-100 text-amber-900' : 'text-gray-900'}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as you and was able to find a solution. Try adding 'relative z-10' to the 'enterTo' attribute like this:

enterTo="transform scale-100 opacity-100 relative z-10".

I noticed that the  element rendered under the  component had a position of "absolute", so we need to add "relative" positioning to let the  element know where it belongs. The z-index property can then be used to make the options appear above the option button. Hope this helps!